# Search for a keyword on one page, have the results show up on another page? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, search, input, filter

I am creating a website for new ex-pats living in the Tokyo area. The site intends to help them easily find accommodation, schooling, places to eat and party, and other jobs in and around the Tokyo area. On the home page, I have a search box in the job section, when a user searches for a job, I don't want the results to show up on the home page, I want the results to show up on another page (in this case, the jobs page) of the website.

How would I go about using the value of the search box to filter through results on another page of the site? I have looked through many tutorials, but I can't really find what I am looking for.

If people want the code, I'll paste it here, however, I don't think it is necessary, as I just want someone to show me how to grab a value from an input, and use that value to filter through, at this point in time, a hardcoded list of jobs on another page.

Many thanks to anyone who takes time out of their day to help me with this problem, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters maybe it will help you out.